# R cca and predict.cca in Vegan

Tags: r, prediction, vegan

I have a species table count (data) which consists on species discrete counts (columns) per sample (row). The samples are divided in 2 categories: control and stress which are represented in a design file by a single column: Condition.
My idea: remove 10 samples (test), do a CCA on the (data - 10 samples) (train) and use the CCA to predict the coordinates of the 10 samples.

> train.cca <- cca(train ~ Condition, data=design)

Here are the results:

> Eigenvalues for constrained axes:
>    CCA1 
>   0.078
>
> 123 unconstrained eigenvalues (CA1...CA123)

I can represent the cca object with plot(train.cca):
[image]

Colours: blue(control) and red(stress).

The axes are built on CCA1 coordinates and the first unconstrained eigenvalue (CA1).
Next, I tried to predict the test data (the 10 samples):

> predict(object=train.cca, model="CCA", type="wa", newdata=test)

this function gives me a set of 10 CCA1 coordinates:

> CCA1
>   0.92
>   0.25
>   0.13
>   0.41
>   1.49
>   0.18
>   0.99
>   1.44
>   2.03
>   0.17

My question is: how can I place these on the plot? All vegan examples (?predict.cca) have several CCA coordinates, so I am stuck with this 1-dimensional output that I can't represent in the plot (I miss the 10 CA1 coordinates). Am I doing the right thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true, that **vegan** only returns scores for one component (`"CCA"` or `"CA"`) in `predict`. So you have to get the components separately and combine them with `cbind()` if you want to have results from several components, like in this case when the `CCA` component has only one axis:

```
ax1 <- predict(object=train.cca, model="CCA", type="wa", newdata=test)
ax2 <- predict(object=train.cca, model="CA", rank=1, type="wa", newdata=test)
ax12 <- cbind(ax1,ax2)
points(ax12) # to add points to an existing grapch
```